# How to Clear or reset Cookie values in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was trying to reset or clear Cookie values, not the entire cookie for which I am setting. So the issue is when I try to process the transaction on Page 1 and go to the Page 2 and come back to Page 1 it is good (for the first time) but however when again I try to make some changes in Page 1 and go to the Page 2 and come back to Page 1 it is showing me the first selected values. The issue is the cookie values are not getting cleared (after the first time) or getting reset for the second transaction (second time). There are two different methods are being called Page_Load and SavePage so Next button will trigger SavePage method and when I try to come back to Page 1 Page_load is getting fired. The code I used in the both methods are.

Can anyone please help me resetting the cookie values or clearing the cookie values for the first after setting. Thanks.

Page_Load Method

```
blnCSRVerify = CBool(If(chkCSRVerify.Checked = True, 1, 0))
blnCustomerDecline = CBool(If(chkCustomerDecline.Checked = True, 1, 0))
If CustomerCookie.IsCSRVerify Then
    chkCSRVerify.Checked = True
End If
If CustomerCookie.IsCustomerDecline Then
    chkCustomerDecline.Checked = True
End If
If CustomerCookie.IsSurrenderCredentials <> const_DefaultValForSurrCred Then
    If CBool(CustomerCookie.IsSurrenderCredentials) OrElse CBool(optlstVerification.YesSelected) Then
        optlstVerification.SelectedValue = CStr(1)
    Else
        optlstVerification.SelectedValue = CStr(0)
    End If
End If
```

SavePage()

```
Dim blnCSRVerify As Boolean = False
Dim blnCustomerDecline As Boolean = False
blnCSRVerify = CBool(If(chkCSRVerify.Checked = True, 1, 0))
blnCustomerDecline = CBool(If(chkCustomerDecline.Checked = True, 1, 0))

Dim objContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

Dim objCustomerCookie As HttpCookie = objContext.Request.Cookies("StarsCustomer")

If blnCSRVerify Then
    objCustomerCookie.Values.Set("CSR_Verify", CStr(blnCSRVerify))
End If
If blnCustomerDecline Then
    objCustomerCookie.Values.Set("CustomerDecline", CStr(blnCustomerDecline))
End If

objCustomerCookie.Values.Set("SurrenderCredentials", optlstVerification.SelectedValue.ToString)

objContext.Response.Cookies.Add(objCustomerCookie)
```

Comment: Cookies are a pain to deal with. .Net constantly screws them up. I don't see where you are creating them in the first place or their expiration date. You should consider creating a class to handle these values and use `Session` to store the instance of that class. It will make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks, Session is working fine.